# Static Constructor present inside DLL not getting called in case of REST Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have working web service. I had to use same code and develop REST web service. I have done it. When I was debugging it I found one unusual thing. Static constructors are not being called when I am debugging my `RESTWebService` project.

All business logic is inside one DLL. Both `WebService` and `RESTWebService` projects use this DLL. Following are those static constructor which are present inside DLL. These constructors initialize some static values.

```
//Logger.cs
static Logger()
{
    try
    {
        m_LogLevel = ....;
        m_LogFilePath = ....;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

//Common.cs
static Common()
{
    ERROR_CODES = ....;
    DB_CONNECTION_STRING = ....;
    DB_NOTIFICATION_CONNECTION_STRING = ....;
    DATA_PROVIDER_INVARIANT_NAME = ....;
}
```

All values initialized in constructor are declared as static.

In case of `WebService` project it is initializing all static variables through static constructor. I have verified it by keeping break point to this static constructor. It will hit all static constructor and in the end public constructor of my web service.

But this is not happening in case of `RESTWebService`. All environment is exactly like my `WebService`. But it does not hit static constructor's break point and directly hits `RestWebService`'s public constructor.

What would be the reason behind this? I am new to WCF. Is there any other thing with RESTWebService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't check if it was called via a breakpoint - instead, when an instance/service mthod is called, check if the values are actually initialized. Or try to log something from the static constructor and see if it was called.

The static constructor may be called before you have a chance to debug/break on it.

Comment: I have checked it. Data members that has to get initialized from static constructor are not getting initialized.

Comment: @Ajinkya: Please note: The members are only guaranteed to be initialized at the time you first access these classes. So checking earlier is not a good idea and might lead to the impression that they will never be initialized.

Comment: @Ajinkya Are you actually using those types somewhere? If so, those constructors should be called.

Comment: @Daniel: I am not using those types before but still When I am debugging my web service it shows me initialized static value before constructor of web service is called.

Comment: @Ajinkya: But that is nothing you can rely on, as you can see. static constructors are not called upon program startup. They are called when needed.

Comment: @Daniel: OK. Then how static members of mentioned classes are getting initialized in case of WebService? As per requirement I have been asked to use present code of WebService and DLL exactly and create RESTWebService and I have done that exactly.

Comment: @Ajinkya: As I said earlier, the static constructor is guaranteed to have been called before you access any member. So, putting some logging into the startup routine or something similar should do the trick.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: OK. I will check it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The static constructors should still be called, but this will happen when the hosting program first loads your DLL.

It could be that the host (IIS I presume?) has the service loaded before you added your breakpoint.  Try an IISRESET and then check again, you will need to attach to the iis worker process for debugging.

Comment: I have not deployed my project on IIS.

Comment: I am debugging it by starting it in browser. After .svc file is called from directory listing on browser I can start debugging though code.

Comment: In that case it is most likely hosted in IIS or Dev Server.  I do think it is an issue with debugging rather than anything else.  Why not add some tracing if you really want to be sure?